# SQL Task - Set Package variable

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have declared a variable at the package level `compdate` and am testing data flow to the variable by droping an `Execute SQL Task` in the Control Flow of the package.

In the task,

SQL Statement:

```
select ? = (getdate() - 1)
```

Parameter Mappings:

- Variable Name: `User::compdate`
- Direction: `Output`
- Data Type: `DATE`
- Parameter Name: `0`
- Parameter Size: `-1`.

Why am i getting error:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "declare @compdate date
set @compdate = (getdate() ..." failed with the following error: "Syntax error or access violation". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Comment: I am confused, what is your question exactly?

Comment: refer to edit....forgot to post the following question ;)

Comment: Are you trying to store the result of an SQL query in your variable?

Comment: yeah trying to return the `getdate - 1` result into the package variable from within the package.  I have done this before but cant seem to find the reference to how to do it.  Or at least something that is straight forward enough to actually digest its meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see why you need to execute an SQL statement to get the previous day as this can be done in various other ways.

To answer your question though, since you are trying to store the result of the SQL query from your **Execute SQL Task** you have to change the SQL statement that you have provided.

**Your new query:**

`SELECT (GETDATE() - 1) AS DateVar`

Where `DateVar` will be the **single** parameter that is returned which you need to map to your variable.

You need to delete your Parameter Mappings as they are not needed. Open up the **Result Set** tab and Add a new result. Set the **Result Name** to be `DateVar` and set the Variable Name to be your variable `User::compdate`

You then need to set up your **Execute SQL Task** to return a Single Row result set in the **General** tab, mapped to your variable. Select **Single row** for the **ResultSet** option.

Working with result sets is explained in great details [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/). Scroll down to the '*Working with a Single-Row Result Set*' section, it has a great example which you can follow.

Comment: can i do this without using ResultSet?  Tried using Output Parameter Mapping but wasnt getting anywhere there either

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you do not want to use ResultSet?

Comment: Try this out: http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/ssis-execute-sql-task-output-parameters

Comment: im looking at full use and understanding....every article uses Result Sets and none of them use the `ReturnValue` direction of ParameterMapping.  Looks like `ReturnSet` is going to be my only option unless someone can provide a good write-up on how to utilize the Input/Output/ReturnValue Direction without utilizing `ResultSet`

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided in my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah playing with the concept written....having issues validating the variables being changed.  Cant output the variable values atm, still trying incorporate a debug/output methodology but running into that part of the validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use without using the `result set`. try with following steps.

1. Create the stored procedure in your respective database. Following
   code is an example.

   ```
   CREATE proc GetYesterDay(@yesterday datetime output)
   as
   Select @yesterday=getdate()-1
   ```
2. Create the ADO.NET connection to run the stored procedure. In which, you can mention the direction of the input and output of the parameters.
3. Create the execute task and configure it as following screenshot.
   [image]
4. Click on Parameter Mapping and configure as following screenshot.
   [image]

Now SSISCompletedDate variable will be filled with respective data.

Hope this helps!